# During Transpose of Spark dataframe. Column names are not getting converted to Row headers

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have Dataframe, name 'tbl' as,

```
summary col1    col2    col3        col200
count   20000   20000   20000       20000
mean    3.02    789.83  8379.02     20.03
std dev 1.02    2.03    0.8         0.56
```

I did transpose using below code,

```
header = [i[0] for i in tbl.select("summary").rdd.map(tuple).collect()]
tt = tbl.select([c for c in tbl.columns if c not in ["summary"]])
rtt = tt.rdd.map(tuple)
rtt1 = rtt.zipWithIndex().flatMap(lambda (x,i): [(i,j,e) for (j,e) in enumerate(x)])
rtt2 = rtt1.map(lambda(i,j,e):(j,(i,e))).groupByKey().sortByKey()
rtt3 = rtt2.map(lambda (i,x):sorted(list(x), cmp=lambda(i1,e1),(i2,e2) : cmp(i1,i2)))

rtt4 = rtt3.map(lambda x: map(lambda (i,y):y, x))
```

Question :

On transpose I am able to generate columns such as,

```
count   Mean    Std dev
20000   3.02    1.02
20000   789.83  2.03
```

But this transformation is missing column header names to identify the transpose is for which variable. I have Dataframe of '3 X 42000' dimension, and all columns are unique, looking ways to identify how I can add column header as Row header on transpose.

Answer (score 1):

How about using Pandas:

```
df = sc.parallelize([(-1.0, 2.0, -3.0), (4.4, 5.1, -6.4)]).toDF()

pdf = df.describe().toPandas()
pdf.T[1:].rename(columns=pdf.T.iloc[0])

   count                mean              stddev   min   max
_1     2  1.7000000000000002   3.818376618407357  -1.0   4.4
_2     2                3.55   2.192031021678297   2.0   5.1
_3     2                -4.7  2.4041630560342617  -6.4  -3.0
```

It is not like you need Spark to handle 120,000 values...

Comment: Thanks it works exactly the way i wanted. But I wanted to know if we can make use of RDD to do the same job. Reason being, the table is huge and converting it to Pandas throwing out of memory exception.